# Pyinstaller WARNING:lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\ymzym\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python39.dll

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I was running `pyinstaller --onedir --icon="Ico.ico Encrypt.py` command but it wasn't successful. I have to convert my Python project to 32-bit exe file because I want to make my program work with Windows XP SP3 too so I have Python 3.9.3 (32-bit). I tried repairing Python but it makes no sense. Can anyone help me?

Here is the log of pyinstaller: It stops the task and returns to cmd after `14546 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\ymzym\PyCharmProjects\YLMZ 3.0\Encrypt.py`

```
218 INFO: Python: 3.9.3
218 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.21343-SP0
218 INFO: wrote C:\Users\ymzym\PyCharmProjects\YLMZ 3.0\Encrypt.spec
234 INFO: UPX is not available.
234 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\ymzym\\PyCharmProjects\\YLMZ 3.0',
 'C:\\Users\\ymzym\\PyCharmProjects\\YLMZ 3.0']
281 INFO: checking Analysis
281 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
281 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
297 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
328 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
355 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6360 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\ymzym\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
6360 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\ymzym\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39-32\\lib'
13760 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
14074 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
14169 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\ymzym\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python.exe
14488 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\ymzym\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python39.dll
14546 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\ymzym\PyCharmProjects\YLMZ 3.0\Encrypt.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by completely uninstalling Python 3.9 32-bit and installing Python 3.9 64-bit, after that installing Python 3.9 32-bit again.